# IntelliJ highlight errors and warnings more prominent

Tags: java, intellij-idea

In IntelliJ I find it cumbersome to find syntax errors and warnings:

Warnings are only listed on the right side at the scroll bar.
Errors are displayed in red - and the at the right side of the scroll bar.

Breakpoints on the other hand are highlited extremly prominent on the left bar of the editor plus a shadow in the whole line.

How to change / customize the style that errors and warnings are more prominent e.g. underlined like in eclipse?

[image: IntelliJ default syntax colors]

Comment: Be default IDEA underlines (most kinds of) errors. Can you show a screenshot of what it looks like for you? And yes: you can certainly customize how various states are displayed under Editor -> Color Scheme -> General -> Errors & Warnings.

Comment: Indeed, you can customize the colors for e.g. Settings (Preferences on macOS) | Editor | Color Scheme | General | Errors and Warnings | **Error**. A related request: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-166310

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can edit your color scheme or change it to another one. Maybe that solves the problem.
Go to **settings > editor > Color Scheme > General**.
you can edit your error or warning style.
Maybe adding a background or foreground color will help

Example making **"Unknown symbol"** and **"Unused symbol"** more prominent:

[image]